# Check the email message size limit with Python

Tags: python, email, size, limit

Can someone tell me, how could I check the size limit of an email message.
So, if all attachements together exceeded the limit, I could send them in more messages. And lets say that each attachement is smaller than limit size.

Im using python 2.7 (*email*, *smtplib* modules).

Any suggestions, samples, links.. would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, I found that out :)
`import smtplib;   
 smtp = smtplib.SMTP('server.name');   
 smtp.ehlo();   
 max_limit_in_bytes = int( smtp.esmtp_features['size'] );`

Comment: You can add the above as an answer to your question, no need to put it in a comment :)

Comment: I know, I will, but I cannot answer my question within first 8 hours :\ Thank's anyway :)

Answer (score 12):

Ok, I found that out :)

```
import smtplib    
smtp = smtplib.SMTP('server.name')    
smtp.ehlo()    
max_limit_in_bytes = int( smtp.esmtp_features['size'] )
```

This returns size limit (in bytes) of entire email (with header, subject, message text...).